# Is there a way to shrink-wrap only a section of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Is there a way to shrink-wrap only a selection of mesh to another without effecting the whole mesh?

When I shrink wrap a mesh to another mesh, sometimes I lose a lot of data on the other side of my object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is a vertex group. You can assign a value from 0.0 to 1.0 to any vertex in the group and the Shrinkwrap Modifier will only partially or fully affect verts within the group with a value > 0.0

That way most of your mesh can remain unchanged. Many modifiers have that option.

The green plane has a vertex group including all verts, but the outer two rows have a weight of 0.0 (blue) and the Shrinkwrap is guided by this vertex group. Excluding them from the group would have the same effect.

[image]

The option to have some verts react partially to the shrinkwrap offers nice solutions to gradually adhere to a surface. Look how the bevel of the small cylinder behaves:

[image]

Comment: Also related video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s&ab_channel=MaxPuliero

Answer (score 5):

You can add to **Vertex Group** part of the mesh that should be affected by **Shrinkwrap** modifier, then choose this group in the modifier itself.

[image: final]